# Change colour/font-weight of axis label if it belongs in a list

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, bar-chart

So I'm creating a bar chart with a lot of entries. On the y-axis it just shows the value of what ever label/entry there is on the x-axis. So all in all I get a lot of bars with different heights - as it should be.

Now, some of the x-axis labels/entries are more important than others. So I have created a list that contains all the important labels/entries. My idea is now that I would like to change the colour or font-weight (making them bold) of those labels/entries that are contained in the list. But I'm really not sure how to do this.

The plot code I'm using now is just:

```
plt.bar(indexes, values, width, color="#3F5D7D", edgecolor="#111111", align='center')
plt.xticks(indexes, labels, fontsize=10, rotation='vertical')
plt.xlim([-0.5,indexes.size-0.5])
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.20, right=0.95, top=0.95, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
plt.show()
```

where `indexes` is the index of each label/entry, `values` are of course the values of those, and in the `plt.xticks` I just change the `indexes` with the `labels`.

I then have a list of labels, let's call it `main_labels = ['important_label1', 'important_label2', 'important_label3'...]` and so on. And yes, now I would like it so when a label is a part of this `main_labels` list it will get bold-faced or another colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the `main_labels`, find out the position of the label in the `labels` list and change the respective ticklabel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
indexes = [1,2,3,5,6]
values = [8,6,4,5,3]
width = 0.8
labels = ["cow","ox","pig","dear","bird"]
main_labels = ["ox", "pig", "bird"]


plt.bar(indexes, values, width, color="#3F5D7D", edgecolor="#111111", align='center')
plt.xticks(indexes, labels, fontsize=10, rotation='vertical')
plt.xlim([0.5,max(indexes)+0.5])
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.20, right=0.95, top=0.95, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)

ticklabels = [t for t in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()]
for l in main_labels:
    i = labels.index(l)
    ticklabels[i].set_color("red")
    ticklabels[i].set_fontweight("bold")

plt.show()
```

[image]